# Array row numbers where some condition is true, in Julia

Tags: julia

If I have

```
julia> a  = [1 0; 2 1; 3 1; 7 0; 5 1; 4 0;]
6×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0
 2  1
 3  1
 7  0
 5  1
 4  0
```

What's the fastest way to get the numbers of the rows where the second column is equal to 1? Or alternatively, a mask which is true when the second column is one and false otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: Also `find(view(a,:,2))` works (and another 10x faster on my machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the natural way is `find(a[:, 2] .== 1)`.
Should be fast too, although speed may depend on size of `a`.

EDIT as of this writing (February 2021, Julia 1.5.3 although I don't know when the change occurred) there is no `find`. this works: `findall(a[:, 2] .== 1)`

Comment: Thanks. What does the . in the .== mean?

Comment: It's an elementwise comparison. If `a` is an Array, `a == 1` will always return `false`, because 1 is not an Array; but `a .== 1` will return an Array of the same size as `a` with `true` in the positions of `a` where there is a 1.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using comprehension, but it is slower.

```
julia> pos = [i for i in 1:size(a,1) if a[i,2] == 1]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
2
3
5
```

Comment: Actually, for small matrices, I'm finding that the comprehension is _much_ faster. Not so for large matrices, though.